# C# generic method value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, templates, generics

I need to write method, that returns children of generic class in `List`. I wrote something like this :

```
static List<Model<T>> Get<T>( string value ) where T : Model<T>
{
    switch( value )
    {
        case "ROLE":
        return GetRoles();
    }
    return new List<Model<T>>();
}
```

`GetRoles()` returns `List<Role>`, where `Role : Model<Role>`. 
But visual studio tells me that it cannot convert `List<Role>` to `List<Model<T>>`.

Comment: For future reference, this is a **generic method** not a **template function**. C++ templates and C# generics are similar but not the same - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b.aspx

Comment: Class is generic too?

Comment: Yes any time you see `<...>` in C# it's **generic** not **template**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is that `List<Role>` is not the same as `List<Model<T>>` even if `Role` is a `Model<Role>`

Example, you have two classes:

```
public class Bar : Model<Foo>
{

}

public class Foo : Model<Foo>
{

}
```

and create a list:

```
var fooList = new List<Foo>();
```

if you could cast it to `List<Model<Foo>>` :

```
var modelList = (List<Model<Foo>>) fooList ; // not possible
```

than you should be able to add new Bars to list:

```
modelList.Add(new Bar());
```

But that is still a list of `Foo` and it could have only Foo objects.

As a solution you could try to cast your Role to Model:

```
static List<Model<T>> Get<T>(string value)  where T:Model<T>
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case "ROLE":
            return GetRoles().Cast<Model<T>>().ToList();
            break;
    }
    return new List<Model<T>>();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand this. But is there any solution for such task? I need to switch between `value` and return some List of `Model<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `List<T>` is not **covariant**. What that means is that if you were allowed to do this, the caller would think it had a `List<Model<T>>` but in fact would have a `List<Role>` - if you then tried adding an instance of another class derived from `Model<T>` to your list it would fail. C# won't let you do that.

Instead, you could explicitly convert your result to `List<Model<T>>` using:

```
return new List<Model<T>>(GetRoles());
```